# What is this 'findmydeviced' in my location icon on the top menu bar?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, geolocation

I have location services on (for Maps & Safari only) and I randomly get this location notification on the top menu bar saying:
" Apps using location: findmydeviced"

What does this mean?

Answer (score 6):

"findmydeviced" is a daemon process that runs on OS X when you have enabled the "[Find My Mac](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH14345?locale=en_US)" option under the iCloud preference pane.

For some reason, it doesn't show up under "Security and Privacy" as an authorised system service (although this could be by design so that a non-Apple savvy thief wouldn't find it if s/he searched there).

If you no longer want to be able to track the location of your Mac via iCloud, you can uncheck the option by navigating to the iCloud preference pane. You may need to reboot in order for the daemon to unload fully.

Comment: Does it waste battery?

Comment: It should only run for a very short amount of time so the energy impact should be negligible

Comment: @StuartH so it reopens?

Comment: @mais-oui, it will reopen every so often to update the location of the Mac, most likely if you change networks or reboot. If it is constantly loading there may be an issue with permissions so I would boot in to Safe Mode to do a disk check then reboot and see if it persists. Also check Console for errors.

Comment: I am running macOS Sierra 10.12.4, there are three related services `com.apple.findmymacmessenger` 
`com.apple.icloud.findmydeviced` 
`com.apple.findmymacd`. I have my mac disabled, but `com.apple.icloud.findmydeviced`  is still running according to `sudo launchctl list | grep find`